# How to add more margin on top of the old one using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, margin

The title says it all, how can I add more margin on top of the old one? So lets say I have this var: `var playerPossition = $('#player').css('margin-top')` its current margin is 375px, lets say I want to make it 275px how could I accomplish this? Thanks for your time!

Comment: @SleekGeek I just want to have one function that adds or remove margin using a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the magin-top into a number that you can do math on

```
    //This returns a string "375px" we need to isolate the number
    var margin_height = $('#player').css('margin-top');
    //.split will turn the string into an array breaking on the parameter
    //"375px" becomes ["375", "x"];
    var margin_top = margin_height.split("p");
    //Now we just need to grab the number from the array
    margin_top = margin_top[0]
```

Then you will need to subtract your number

```
    margin_top -= 100;
```

And finally change the margin-top to the desired amount

```
    $('#player').css('margin-top', margin_top);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.